# cannot do the INSERT statement.. it doesn't detect my table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
INSERT INTO Users (userId, username, password, email, fname, lname, usertype) 
Values(1, 'admin','admin','abc@gmail.com','firstname','lastname','admin')
```

Error Message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'Users'.

I'm using windows authentication in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I was creating tables and inserting data to my previous tables. When I create a new table it doesn't detect from my SQL statement of inserting values.

Please Help!

Comment: Try using the full Table name `[DatabaseName].[owner].[tablename]`.

Comment: can you do `SELECT * FROM Users` ???

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sql Server Management Studio, make sure you have selected the correct database.

[image]

Comment: It is the correct database my other tables in the database works... Are there any way to add values without the statement? :-/

Comment: The error message is stating that there is not a table named `Users` in the database you are working with. Are you sure you spelled the table name correctly when creating it?

Answer (score 1):

check to see that the schema/owner of the table is the same as the user you are trying to execute your insert statement as. For instance `[dbo].[Users]` is not the same as `[user1234].[Users]` and you'll have to fully-qualify your schema and table name

```
INSERT INTO [user1234].[Users] ...
```

An easy way to check would be to expand your tables in Sql Management Studio, expand your database and then Tables node

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your connection string specifies the correct database.  You may be connecting to "Master" by default.

Comment: It is the correct database my other tables in the database works... Are there any way to add values without the statement? :-/ –  CRKZZ 1 min ago   edit   delete

Comment: Have you tried this EXACT statement:  
`INSERT INTO [Users] (userId, username, password, email, fname, lname, usertype) 
Values(1, 'admin','admin','abc@gmail.com','firstname','lastname','admin')`

Notice the braces around the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to select correct database. Here in this case I have table in RepairDB database and please check it's selected in top.
[image: I have added record in same table and it's successful]

Comment: It is the correct database my other tables in the database works... Are there any way to add values without the statement? :-/ –  CRKZZ 1 min ago   edit   delete

Answer (score 0):

it started working just like that.. i guess SQL sever management studio doesn't properly work with windows 8.1.. sometimes it crashes too..

i was using the correct database and same SQL statement works for my other table.. and yeah table names are correct too..

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.